# A qué se debe éste error asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Me surgió este problema en visual studio, trabajando en asp.net c# y no sé como solucionarlo, a alguien le ha pasado?

[image: problema al compilar la solucion]

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una referencia a tu proyecto con la librería **System.Web.DataVisualization** y se solucionara tu problema.

Comment: ya lo tenía agregado, sigue igual, recompilé la solución pero no logro sacar ese error

Comment: puede ser que tengas que limpiar prueba eso a ver, sino revisa el dll que se genera en la carpeta bin/debug a veces eso también me genera problemas lo que haces es borrar el dll y volverlo a generar

Comment: @FranciscoVargas además de lo que dice Victor Perdomo, le sugieron limpiar la solución `Clean Solution` > luego `Rebuild Solution`. Si el problema persiste, cierre y abra nuevamente Visual Studio. Me ha pasado veces en que "a pesar de seguir estos pasos" tuve que cerrar y abrir Visual Studio y el Buil de hace correctamente.

Comment: He hecho todo lo que mencionas, hasta reiniciado el iis, reiniciar el sistema, limpiar, compilar, volver a compilar la solución, pero nada resulta :(

Comment: re compila cada capa del proyecto también me ha pasado que me da error por eso

Comment: re compile cada capa y el problema persiste...

Comment: @VictorPerdomo podrías ayudarme por teamviewer por favor?

Comment: Lo siento amigo estoy en el trabajo sino con mucho gusto, es lo máximo que puedo ayudarte por acá solamente